# Report RDLC not showing data

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have create a report rdlc and use report viewer to view this report .But data not showing,just table header shown.
please help me to resolve this issue.

```
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\HRMS\NewHRMS\AllEmpProfiles.rdlc"
            Dim params(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
            params(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("deptName", "Finance")
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
            Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Attached file[image: link].

Comment: Are you setting the DataSource property?

Comment: @BrianMStafford thanks for respnse,yes,its working with table but this contain stored procedure so thats why not working

Comment: No matter where the data comes from you likely end up with a DataTable.  Is that being attached to the DataSource property?  I don't see this happening in your sample code.

Comment: i don't know how to pass?Can you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code showing how I usually configure a report.  The line you are missing is the `DataSources.Add`:

```
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "<your rdlc>"
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", <your data>))
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter("deptName", "Finance"))
  ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

`"DataSet1"` corresponds to a name inside your rdlc file.

`<your data>` corresponds to data that you provide.  It can be a DataTable, IEnumerable, BindingSource, etc.

Comment: Is `empprofiles` a DataTable or an xsd file?  Based on the screenshot, perhaps you need to use `EmpProfile.GetAllEmpProfiles` which does appear to be a DataTable.